# Ordenação de vetor de vetores de caracteres com qsort <stdlib.h>

Tags: c, array-multidimensional, quicksort

O programa seguinte não está ordenando o vetor de vetores de chars corretamente, mas não sei por que. Talvez seja minha função auxiliar "cmpstr" que não está retornando o valor certo em alguns casos, ou minha chamada do qsort...O que está errado?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //qsort
#include <string.h> //strcmp

int cmpstr(const void* a, const void* b){ // função auxiliar do qsort
    const char* aa = (const char*)a;
    const char* bb = (const char*)b;
    return strcmp(aa, bb);
}

char equipe[1000][5000][50]; //array de arrays de arrays de caracteres

int main()
{
    int qtd_alunos, qtd_times, qtd_membros;
    scanf("%d %d", &qtd_alunos, &qtd_times);
    qtd_membros = qtd_alunos/qtd_times;

    for(int j=0; j<qtd_membros; j++){   //recebe nomes
        for(int i=0; i<qtd_times; i++){
            scanf("%s", equipe[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(int j=0; j<qtd_times; j++){  //ordena cada equipe [deveria ordenar]
        qsort(equipe[j], qtd_membros, sizeof(char*), cmpstr);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<qtd_times; i++){  //exibe a composição de cada equipe
        printf("Time %d\n", i+1);
        for(int j=0; j<qtd_membros;j++){
            printf("%s\n", equipe[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possivelmente tens os ciclos (ou os indices) no `scanf()` trocados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errado

```
    qsort(equipe[j], qtd_membros, sizeof(char*), cmpstr);
    //                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

O array `equipe` tem tamanho `sizeof (char) * 50 * 5000 * 1000` (o mesmo que `sizeof equipe`).
Cada elemento desse array (cada equipe) tem tamanho `sizeof (char) * 50 * 5000` (o mesmo que `sizeof equipe[0]`).
Cada elemento de cada equipe (cada membro) tem tamanho `sizeof (char) * 50` (o mesmo que `sizeof equipe[0][0]`).

---

Solução

```
    qsort(equipe[j], qtd_membros, sizeof equipe[0][0], cmpstr);
    //                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Arrays e ponteiros **não** são a mesma coisa. Aconselho uma leitura da secção 6 do [FAQ do comp.lang.c](http://c-faq.com/).